# error:Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'Log.CUstomUser' in Django

Tags: python, django

When a user wants to register, my website show this error:

> Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for
>   'Log.CUstomUser'

I use `import AbstractUser` in my model

I work with Django freamwork python

Model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser , 
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

View:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .forms import Register
from django.shortcuts import render , render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt
def Home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form =  Register(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Greate")
    else:
        form = Register()
        return render_to_response('home.html' , {'form':form})
```

Forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Register(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    number = forms.IntegerField()
    age = forms.IntegerField()

    class meta:
        model = User
        field = (

            'number',
            'age',
            'username',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'

        )
```

Please, help me to fix my error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change this var in settings?
 `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.CustomUser'`

More details you can get [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: Yes i write AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.CustomUser in setting

Answer (score 0):

Im new in django but i have an idea for ur error maybe help.
try to replace `model = CustomUser` instead `model=User` in Form.py as below:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Register(UserCreationForm):
        #blah blah

    class meta:
        model = CustomUser    #hereeeeee
        field = (
          #your field
        )
```